# How can i do password protect a document using Office js in Word 2016 for Mac?

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office365api

I want to protect word document using office js in word 2016. I didn't find any protection API for office js.

I want to protect a sensitive or confidential document by using a password to help prevent others from changing or even opening your document.

How can i protect my word document using office JS? If API not available, what is time line to available for us?

Keyur Patel